# R programming Word cloud for Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am new to shiny and need your guidance. I have a data set which have 5 columns: Comments , category , country , language , date

I want to create a word-cloud of text in the "comments" columns but i am unable to do that, i went through different blogs and tutorials but I can not find any particular explanation on this.

In Comments column i have different sentences in English language. I just simply want a word-cloud of that column. It is easy in simple R but in shiny i am getting confused as it seems bit tricky. Kindly help. Thankyou

Comment: could you please share what type of code you have tried so far, it would be easier for us to replicate the same. OR You haven't started anything yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you can do is, you can extract all the comments from the table by subset or what ever way you want and then can save the same as a text file on you system, 
further you can create a word-cloud referring the link below :
[Word-Cloud Help](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hclPORTzMnE)

this takes a text/plain file as an input and will create a word-cloud for you on all the comments collected by your table.

Comment: So data is added in the code itself. Did you mean that you don't want to pass a file rather just text in your code?

Comment: What i am saying is that i want to give a file inside my code i dont want to upload a file from a browser like in the example video you gave me.

Comment: So in what ever variable you were planning to store the file, you can save the data directly in the same and do like it is done in the video at 5min 45 sec time zone. Please check.

Comment: I was able to do it by a tutorial from somewhere else. Thanks For your help bud.